# adb push only if file doesn't exist or has changed

Tags: adb

For a program I am using ADB to transfer a file from the computer to mobile phone.

Using `adb push` overwrites every existent file and thus takes ages to finish.
`adb sync` does only push the file if it exists on the phone AND contains other data than the local version.

Is there any midway solution? I want the file to be transferred if it doesn't exist or is changed, but not, if it is the same as on the computer. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this is to first check if the file exists and if it does then sync it and if it does not then push.

Skeleton for a batch script to do this:

```
FILENAME_RESULT=$(adb shell ls / | tr -d '\015'|grep '^fileName$')
if [ -z "$FILENAME_RESULT" ];
then
    REM adb push because the file was not found
else
    REM adb sync because the file was found
fi
```

Comment: adb sync takes a directory, not a file, how can you do this with one file?

Answer (score 5):

```
adb push --sync /local/file /sdcard/remote/file
```

From `adb --help`

`adb push [--sync] [-zZ] LOCAL... REMOTE copy local files/directories to device --sync: only push files that are newer on the host than the device. -z: enable compression -Z: disable compression`

Answer (score 0):

There's a really easy way to do this with adb-sync (https://github.com/google/adb-sync).

adb-sync is a tool to synchronize files between a PC and an Android device using the ADB (Android Debug Bridge).